# Ubuntu Pavilion 15 bluetooth doesnt detect mouse Logitech

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, logitech

I just buy a new computer HP Pavilion 15 eg3018ns its seen that is coming with a mediatek WIFI/Bluetooth card.

I just install Ubuntu 22.04.02,in the windows partition everything works fine, but Ubuntu doesn't detect my Logitech Anywhere 3 (in my works laptop a Thinkpad with Ubuntu works fine), the card detect and I'm using a pixel bud earphones.

There is something I can do to fix this? I could check the wifi/Bluetooth card if that is the problem.

```
lsusb; uname -r; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:5477 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:3567 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
5.19.0-50-generic
[    1.381198] ACPI: thermal: [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    3.171451] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_16.bin (v2.16)
[    3.182914] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.182981] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.182984] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.183160] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.183165] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.183171] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.196204] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_70.1.1.bin version 70.1
[    3.196216] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin version 7.9
[    3.279410] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____010000, Build Time: 20220209150915
[    3.383277] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.383282] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.383288] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.558635] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    4.558641] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    4.654334] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    4.654340] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    5.964123] Bluetooth: hci0: Device setup in 2634407 usecs
[    6.029628] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v1.00
[    6.029640] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is supported
[   36.884922] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   36.884936] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   36.884945] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Look at the system startup logs, and watch your OS discover the hardware with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; uname -r; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: I just edit with the response